# gcloud run replace, not deploying a new revision, when no change in the file

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud build file that's build three containers and push it to the registry, last step is to update the cloud run service with multiple containers that using this images.

I have a service.yaml, this files using the :latest tag on all three container images file thats working fine when it's deployed the first time. But if I running the the build again, the containers will be updated and the gcloud replace ./service.yaml is running without any issue, but there is no new revision in cloud run.

If i update for example the timeout time in the service.yaml file from 300 to 299 and run it again, is a new revision created.

I don't now how can i trigger a new revision if there no changes in the file because i use the latest tag for the images.

Comment: Please check this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#:~:text=You%20can%20deploy%20a%20new,Each%20revision%20created%20is%20immutable.)

Comment: I know this docs, what you mean? The deployment works, but only when the yaml file has a change a new revision is created

Comment: After the build, the images has changes, i can see that the sha has changed in the artifacts registry.

Comment: Can you check if there is any change in the service.yaml file before and after the first deployment? if there can you differences?.Also please share the minimal reproducible configuration/code.

Comment: Hi @VaidehiJamankar exactly this is the problem, there is no change after the first deployment because in the yaml file is the :latest tag used, so the deployment is done after the building the new containers, the new containers has the tag :latest. In the yaml file has no change done.

Comment: Can you share your yaml file also minimal reproducible steps for configuration/code or link you followed and changes you did,so I can try that at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tag from `:latest` to the actual version of images.

Comment: Yes and no, this works one time, after that no new revision is deployed